# C++ - Reading a line without getline

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to read user entered data from the stream and then store it in a custom String class.

To my best knowledge, std::getline() can route data only to std::string , that is why I need to come up with something else, as **my project is not allowed to use std::string class.**

My code looks like this:

```
String street();
std::cout << "Street: "; std::cin >> std::noskipws;
char c='\0';
while(c!='\n'){
    std::cin >> c;
    street=street+c;
}std::cin >> std::skipws;
    
int bal=0;
std::cout << "Balance: "; std::cin >> bal;
```

Comment: If you read the documentation on [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), you probably wouldn't have needed to ask this question. It won't skip leading whitespace and that's it. Just use `std::getline()`. You are claiming that `std::getline()` is out of play because of something you did. Undo that, and use the right tool for the job.

Comment: @sweenish My project is not allowed to use std::string. To my best knowledge, std::getline() can route data only to std::string , that is why I need to come up with something else.

Comment: So why in the world did you phrase your inability to use `std::getline()` the way you did? It's misleading at best.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but note that `String street();` declares a function named `street` that takes no arguments and returns a `String`. Just like `int f();`.

Comment: The `std::cin >> c; street=street+c;` loop is a huge waste of time.. THat's simply a bad practice they shouldn't teach you do. How about declaring your own operator>> for `String`?  `std::istream::getline`  available for `cin` doesn't use `string`, it uses a character pointer, so you can create operator which uses that

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thank you! This approach solves my issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my best knowledge, std::getline() can route data only to std::string , that is why I need to come up with something else, as my project is not allowed to use std::string class.

Note that [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) are two separate functions. The former will work with `std::string` while the latter will work with C-style strings (i.e. sequences of characters that are terminated by a null character).

Therefore, if you are not allowed to use `std::string`, then you can still use `std::istream::getline`, for example like this:

```
char line[200];
String street;

std::cout << "Street: ";

if ( std::cin.getline( line, sizeof line ) )
{
    //the array "line" now contains the input, and can be assigned
    //to the custom String class
    street = line;
}
else
{
    //handle the error
}
```

This code assumes that your custom `class String` has defined the [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) for C-style strings.

If it is possible that the lines will be larger than a fixed number of characters and you want to support such lines, then you could also call `std::istream::getline` in a loop:

```
char line[200];
String street;

std::cout << "Street: ";

for (;;)
{
    std::cin.getline( line, sizeof line );

    street += line;

    if ( std::cin.bad() )
    {
        //TODO: handle error and break loop, for example by
        //throwing an exception
    }

    if ( !std::cin.fail() || std::cin.eof() )
        break;

    std::cin.clear();
}
```

This code assumes that `operator +=` is defined for `class String`.

This loop will continue forever until

1. `getline` succeeds (i.e. it is able to extract (but not store) the newline character), or
2. end-of-file is reached (`eofbit` is set), or
3. an error occurs (`badbit` is set).

Comment: The downside to this approach is that it limits the max line length. If you need to handle variable-length lines with no max, like `std::getline()` does, then consider using `std::istream::get()` instead of `operator>>` to read individual characters until `'\n'` is reached. To avoid unnecessary memory reallocations, you can read into an intermediate `char[]` buffer, flushing that to the `String` object whenever the `char[]` fills up or `'\n'` is reached.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In my experience, reading one character at a time is rather inefficient. I have therefore added a solution which calls `getline` in a loop, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the C function "getchar()" to read a single character from standard input. This link describes it: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-getc-getchar-read-character.

Here is my code:

```
String street=();
std::cout << "Street: ";
char c='\0';
while(c!='\n'){
    c = getchar();
    street=street+c;
}

int bal=0;
std::cout << "Balance: "; std::cin >> bal;
cout << street << endl;
```

I hope this will help you, and I recommend you make an independent function that will read line from standard input and whose return type will be "String". You can declare it as:

```
String readLine();
```

And I also recommend you to pay attention to that while loop because string that is obtained from that loop will have character '\n' at the end of it.

Comment: You are linking to [platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computing_platform)-specific documentation of the function `getchar`, which contains information that does not apply to most other platforms. It would probably be better to refer to platform-neutral documentation, such as [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar).

Comment: I am not sure if it is a good idea to mix C-style I/O with C++-style I/O, because this will only work when [std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio) is true, unless the input stream is used exclusively for C-style I/O. It may be better to use [std::istream::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) if you want to read a single character.